# Chatbase messages are not showing in GUI

Tags: chatbase

I have integrated Chatbase into a voice application, when the user says a certain "Intent", it will be send and logged in Chatbase.

However, while the messages are sending fine (they are returning 200 in the send callback) - there appears to be nothing in the Chatbase console. I have read saying things can take 6 hours - it has now been 24 hours and there is still nothing!

Here is my implementation:

```
function sendChatbaseMessage(ad, intent) {
Chatbase.setApiKey(process.env.MY_CHATBASE_ID)
   .setPlatform('Alexa') 
   .setVersion('1.0') 
   .setAsTypeUser()
   .newMessage()
   .setTimestamp(Date.now().toString())
   .setMessage(`STATE: ${ad.Session[SessionVars.SkillState]}`)
   .setUserId(ad.Util.getUserId())
   .setIntent(intent)
   .setAsHandled()
   .setCustomSessionId(ad.Util.getSessionId())
   .send()
   .then((data) => {
     console.log("Chatbase message sent: ", data.getCreateResponse())
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log("Error sending chatbase message", prettifyJSON(err.stack))
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The information I was logging in my app was showing the the "cohorts" section of the web GUI.